# Frame id /generic_camera_link, with Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, frames, camera, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using tf to transform Point Cloud coords which I receive from kinect (image coords) to real world (gazebo coords). First of all, I had to create a publisher for the /world frame, because launching tf tf_monitor no frame was published. I thought this was enough and I believed that, receiving a coordinate frame from the cloud, this was automatically published somewhere in the kinect controller. However, it seems I was wrong, in fact I'm receiving this error:

Frame id /generic_camera_link does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /odom exists with parent /world.
Frame /world exists with parent NO_PARENT.

EDIT: I'm using gazebo_ros_openni_kinect controller for Kinect

EDIT 2: Are there other faster methods to obtain the same results?

How can I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44306/frame-id-/generic_camera_link,-with-kinect/) by [webrot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3242/webrot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-22**:
What do you mean faster? You can either add a call to `static_transform_publisher` to a `.launch` file or do the same thing programmatically. Please see [tf Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [static_transform_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher) to create a link between `/world` frame and whatever you need.

To make it easier to understand interconnections between frames use

```
$ rosrun tf2_visualization frame_viewer.py
```

It will produce a graph with all available frames and their links.

---

EDIT #1:

Run above mentioned command in terminal and check if there any disconnected nodes (single or a group) on the graph.

---

EDIT #2:

Run the following on terminal but substitute `<point_cloud_topic>` with appropriate topic name:

```
$ rostopic echo -n 1 <point_cloud_topic>/header/frame_id
```

Use frame ID from output of this command to create a new `tf` frame linked to `/odom`:

```
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 /odom <point_cloud_frame_id> 100
```

This command will add your Kinect frame as a child to `/odom` frame and will publish it every `100ms`.

You might need to substitute zeros there with appropriate XYZ displacement and YPR orientation. See `static_tranform_publisher` documentation for more details (link provided at the beginning of the answer).

If you run `frame_viewer.py` after that you should see three nodes connected in line from `/world` to `/odom` to `<point_cloud_frame_id>`.

---

EDIT #3:

Question about transformation of point cloud coordinates to fixed frame was already answered [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/34555/point-cloud-point-to-map-coordinates/).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-09-21**:
Thanks for the clear explanation.